# STM32 VCP - Receive data from PC

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32f4, usb-otg

I am using STM32 HAL VCP firmware generated by CubeMX on STM32F4 discovery board. The Virtual COM Port works, I can transmit from the microcontroller to the PC as many messages I want. But in the other direction, from PC to microcontroller I can send only one message. If I try to send a second one, the `static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS (char* Buf, uint32_t *Len)` callback won't be called, and on the PC RealTerm hangs. My client program hangs too, when it tries to write in the COM port second time.

On microntroller side I removed all of my code in `CDC_Receive_FS()`, it returns currently only `USBD_OK`. In the main function there is only a `HAL_Delay()` periodically called, I tried to remove this too, but it had no effect.

Any ideas, what could be the problem?

Comment: Full receive buffer somewhere perhaps, hardware or software handshaking kicking in?

Comment: I posted the answer, there must have been a handshaking issue in the software.

Comment: check this link: [https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Read data from PC to STM32 via USB CDC&currentviews=40](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Read%20data%20from%20PC%20to%20STM32%20via%20USB%20CDC&currentviews=40)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer for my own question. There is a well documentated example on the following webpage:
http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/usb/

First of all, I had to complete the generated code in `static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS (char* Buf, uint32_t *Len)` as it is written in the source above.

After that I had to create and implement the `int VCP_read(void *pBuffer, int size)` function, as it is written in the above mentioned source.

The key point was, that I had to call periodically the `int VCP_read(void *pBuffer, int size)` function, to read out from the buffer the received data. If I don't call this function, the PC can't write next time the COM port.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the answer. For me, the key to this was adding a call to 'USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&USBD_Device);' within the receive callback... 'static int8_t CDC_Itf_Receive(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)'
It looks to be needed to tell the host PC driver that we have received the packet OK.